# Solrnet no results and type cast issues when implementing search

Tags: asp.net, solr, solrnet

I'm trying to get data to display on a webpage from a database and be searchable via a textbox on the page, using solrnet for search and asp.net. I've implemented the search similarly to how it is set up in the docs on solrnet's wiki.  The first problem is that about half the time the code breaks when trying to set up the query, and oddly enough only for specific input strings (I've identified "france", "f", and "a" to break things) with the error message.

```
"Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'."
```

I've tried debugging but it goes pretty deep into the solrnet code and I couldn't even find where it was trying to do this broken conversion.  The other problem is that even when it doesn't break, no results turn up!  I don't know why this is either, though it could have to do with the "defaultfield" of our solr schema.

Anyway, here's the relevant portion of the code; if you need anything else let me know what and I can post it:

```
    public string Search(string text)
    {
        // Solr init stuff
        var solr = SolrOpsCache<Product>.GetSolrOperations();

        // Code will often break pointing this block below
        var matchingProducts = solr.Query(new SolrQuery(text), new QueryOptions {
            Start = 1,
            Rows = 30,
        });

        // This is just formatting the results correctly for the
        // stored proc I have on the database
        List<string> matchingItemCodes = new List<string>();

        foreach (Product p in matchingProducts)
        {
            matchingItemCodes.Add(p.itemCode);
        }
        string itemCodesDelimited = ToDelimitedString(matchingItemCodes, ",");
        return itemCodesDelimited;
    }


    protected void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Search based on what's in the box
        string codes = Search(SearchBox.Text);
        productList = pr.GetProductsByItemcode(codes);
    }
}
```

schema.xml:

```
<schema name="RML Schema" version="1.1">
  <types>
    <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <fieldType name="cat_string" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">      
      <analyzer>  
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>  
      </analyzer>  
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.IntField" />
  </types>

 <fields>   

    <field name="ItemCode" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />  
     <field name="ItemName" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>  
     <field name="RML" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>  
     <field name="Buyer" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>  
     <field name="Vendor" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 

     <field name="AvgCost" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
     <field name="SalePrice" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
     <field name="Profit_Ave" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
     <field name="Profit_MSRP" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
     <field name="OnHand" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
     <field name="IsCommited" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
     <field name="OnOrder" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
     <field name="ATS" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
     <field name="AOH" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 

     <field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
     <field name="Vintage" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
     <field name="Producer" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
     <field name="Country" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
     <field name="Region" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
     <field name="Appellation" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
     <field name="CRU" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
     <field name="Size" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
     <field name="RtrakDept" type="cat_string" indexed="true" stored="true" />

 </fields>
```

And my class for Product

```
public class Product
    {
        [SolrUniqueKey("ItemCode")]
        public string itemCode { get; set; }

        [SolrField("ItemName")]
        public string itemName { get; set; }

        /* Commented out because it's not in the database yet
        [SolrField("RML")]
        public string rml { get; set; }        
        */

        [SolrField("Buyer")]
        public string buyer { get; set; }

        [SolrField("Vendor")]
        public string vendor { get; set; }

        [SolrField("AvgCost")]
        public Nullable<float> avgCost { get; set; }

        [SolrField("SalePrice")]
        public Nullable<float> salePrice { get; set; }

        [SolrField("Profit_Ave")]
        public Nullable<float> profitAve { get; set; }

        [SolrField("Profit_MSRP")]
        public Nullable<float> profitMSRP { get; set; }

        [SolrField("OnHand")]
        public Nullable<int> onHand { get; set; }

        [SolrField("IsCommited")]
        public Nullable<int> isCommited { get; set; }

        [SolrField("OnOrder")]
        public Nullable<int> onOrder { get; set; }        

        [SolrField("ATS")]
        public Nullable<int> ats { get; set; }

        [SolrField("AOH")]
        public Nullable<int> aoh { get; set; }

        [SolrField("Vintage")]
        public string vintage { get; set; }

        [SolrField("Producer")]
        public string producer { get; set; }

        [SolrField("Country")]
        public string country { get; set; }

        [SolrField("Region")]
        public string region { get; set; }

        [SolrField("Appellation")]
        public string appellation { get; set; }

        [SolrField("CRU")]
        public string cru { get; set; }

        [SolrField("Size")]
        public string size { get; set; }

        [SolrField("RtrakDept")]
        public string rtrakDept { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does your `schema.xml` and `Product` class look like? I suspect there is an string field defined in solr schema, which you are mapping to an `int` property of your class.

Comment: Updating the post now, I can't seem to find a miss mapping.  Keep an eye out for anything that looks fishy.

Comment: Nothing stands out. Is there a stacktrace that you can share? perhaps there is more information in the exception?

Comment: This is being discussed in SolrNet forum - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/solrnet/GXq1huRx8TM

Comment: I got it sorted out (mostly).  Turns out it was some weird indexing issue; I have yet to resolve it completely but was able to work around the problem for now.  If anyone (googlers) wants more info on this bug, follow the discussion I posted on the SolrNet forum.